# Maven -- change files in dependency

Tags: maven

So the problem I'm having is that I'm using maven to download a repo with some code that I need for work. It's an automated test and the dependency includes an older version of chrome-driver. The driver itself doesn't work because it's out of date. I have to download and replace the file manually. That's not so much a problem, but every time I `mvn clean` I lose that binary file and have to download it again.

The best thing to do would be to update the repo I'm inheriting from, but I've been told that they'll "get to it" =\ Is there any way I can permanently replace this binary in my current project so I don't have to re-download it when I absentmindedly clean the directory?

Comment: Is your file in a target folder? Did you try moving it somewhere else and updating dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. download the problematic artifact (e.g. jar and the pom)
2. modify the pom.xml and change the old/bad dependency
3. install it into your local repository using the [maven install plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I went into my repo directory and changed out the out dated binary. Thanks!